# How to override paint eventhandler with derived type of PaintEventArgs

Tags: c#, winforms, paintevent

I want to transfer the angle of a line to be drawn  via  a class AnglePaintEvent Args which is derived from PaintEventArgs class.

```
    public class AnglePaintEventArgs : PaintEventArgs
{
    int angle;
    public AnglePaintEventArgs(Graphics graphic, Rectangle rectangle, int Angle) : base(graphic, rectangle)
    {
        angle = Angle;
    }
}
```

The panel’s eventhandler only accepts functions that have the argument PaintEventArgs but not AnglePaintEventArgs. I was not able to cast the args.
Several tries:

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //tried this
        this.panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(AnglePaintEventArgs);
        //tried that
        this.panel1.Paint += new AnglePaintEventArgs;
        this.panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
    }
```

does not work neither.

```
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender,AnglePaintEventArgs e)
```

Is it necessary to derive a new panel object class? Does it help to declare a new delagate with the AnglePaintEventArgs and hook it to the panel object?

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag.

Comment: The `Paint` event is generated by the system and passes the filled `PaintEventArgs` there. You should probably pass the `Angle` value in a different way. It is possible to make an additional property.

Comment: Tag added. I will create another property within the form. But I cannot pass it as a parameter to the function that is called by the event.

Comment: You can store the `Angle` in the `Panel`s  `Tag`property, then you can grap it in the `Paint` eventhandler.

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a bit of an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) because even if you were to succeed in injecting an angle into a custom `PaintEventArgs` class a line and draw it, it's likely to be erased on the next refresh unless you're persisting it in a document of some kind. Same goes for a `Tag`. To draw on any control, call its `Refresh()` method and it will respond by firing the `Paint` message and providing a `Graphics` *blank* canvas to draw on. Given that the effect of having an `angle` property in the *event* argument or a tag would be so ephemeral, it's not a good fit there.

Consider making a `Line` class with the `Angle` property that goes in a `List<object>` that can hold the various shapes you want to draw. You can continue to add more lines to the document, then call `pictureBox.Refresh` whenever there is a new shape to draw.

[image: lines with angles]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
                pictureBox.Paint += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            foreach (var shape in Document)
            {
                if(shape is Line line)
                {                    
                    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.White, line.Width))
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, line.Origin, line.EndPoint);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        for (double angle = 0; angle<360; angle += 15)
        {
            Document.Add(new Line
            {
                Origin = pictureBox.GetCenterPoint(),
                Angle = angle,
                Length = 150,
            });
        }
    }
    List<object> Document { get; } = new List<object>();
}
```

---

```
class Line
{
    public Point Origin { get; set; }
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public Point EndPoint
    {
        get
        {
            double radians = Angle * Math.PI / 180;
            int endX = (int)(Origin.X + Length * Math.Cos(radians));
            int endY = (int)(Origin.Y + Length * Math.Sin(radians));
            return new Point(endX, endY);
        }
    }
    public float Width { get; set; } = 2f;
}
```

---

**Extensions**

```
static partial class Extensions
{
    public static Point GetCenterPoint(this Control control) =>
        new Point(
            control.ClientRectangle.Left + control.ClientRectangle.Width / 2,
            control.ClientRectangle.Top + control.ClientRectangle.Height / 2);
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/angle-of-line-to-be-drawn.git)